# SyncFusion Angular js found no solutions on google for 'The given key was not found in the dictionary'

Tags: angularjs, rdlc, syncfusion

I am creating reportviewer using Syncfusion in angular JS in Asp.net MVC
I have downloaded the community version of syncfusion
My APIController

```
public class Pay_rep_ReportViewerApiController : ApiController, IReportController
{
    public object PostReportAction(Dictionary<string, object> jsonResult)
    {
        try
        {
            var output = ReportHelper.ProcessReport(jsonResult, this);
        }
        catch (Exception exxxx)
        {

        }
        return ReportHelper.ProcessReport(jsonResult, this);
    }

    //Get action for getting resources from the report
    [System.Web.Http.ActionName("GetResource")]
    [AcceptVerbs("GET")]
    public object GetResource(string key, string resourcetype, bool isPrint)
    {
        return ReportHelper.GetResource(key, resourcetype, isPrint);
    }

    //Method will be called when initialize the report options before start processing the report        
    public void OnInitReportOptions(ReportViewerOptions reportOption)
    {
        if (reportOption.ReportModel.ReportPath.Contains("RSSMRP01.rdlc"))
        {
            reportOption.ReportModel.ReportPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/RSSMRP01.rdlc");
        }
        if (reportOption.ReportModel.ReportPath.Contains("~/Views/PayModule/Pay_rep_employee.rdlc"))
        {
            reportOption.ReportModel.ReportPath = System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(reportOption.ReportModel.ReportPath);
        }
    }

    //Method will be called when reported is loaded
    public void OnReportLoaded(ReportViewerOptions reportOption)
    {

    }
}
```

in JSController

```
$scope.reportServiceUrl = '/api/Pay_rep_ReportViewerApi';
$scope.remoteMode = ej.ReportViewer.ProcessingMode.Local;
$scope.rdlReportPath = '~/Views/PayModule/Pay_rep_employee.rdlc';
```

In my view

```
 <div id="container" ej-reportviewer e-reportserviceurl="reportServiceUrl"
      e-processingmode="remoteMode" e-isresponsive="true"
      e-reportpath="rdlReportPath" style="width:100%;height:680px;"
      e-datasources="dataSource"> 
 </div>
```

I get json array in ApiController when I keep breakpoint

```
{{ inProgress = completed,
   isReportLoad = True,
   paramInfo = NoParams,
   reportViewerToken = 930af59b-fd2d-473c-b453-e8df4343ecc7,
   reportViewerID = 930af59b-fd2d-473c-b453-e8df4343ecc7,
   dataSources = , dataSets = , reportParameters = , isRDLC = False,
   errorInfo = , serviceType = Default }}
```

but on the screen with reportviewer I get "The given key was not present in the dictionary.", but the server demo works fine .

[References added](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DX9LB.png)

[image]

Is it feasible to solve it using community version? Thanks in advance

Comment: I removed the try-catch statement from apiController and it is working

Comment: `try
        {
            var output = ReportHelper.ProcessReport(jsonResult, this);
        }
        catch (Exception exxxx)
        {

        }`
these lines were causing the "The given key was not present in the dictionary." error. Commented them out and it is running fine . Thanks mates for spending your valuable time